# GitGraph - scaling the size of the graph

Tags: javascript, git

I am using the GitGraph javascript library - http://gitgraphjs.com/

I am currently using the examples file to see how things work in GitGraph. The link to the example file - https://github.com/nicoespeon/gitgraph.js/blob/develop/examples/index.js

Is there any possible way to scale the graph? I tried overriding CSS styles, the quality of graph diminished greatly.

I was expecting something like a GitGraph.scale option? Is that available?

Answer (score 1):

The main project page doesn't make it easy to link, but it looks like the section titled "Define Your Own Template" is what you're looking for?

EDIT:

OK, with a better understanding of what you're looking for, I played around with it myself, and noticed that the canvas element's `width` and `height` properties are [added to the DOM programmatically in `GitGraph.prototype.render()`](https://github.com/nicoespeon/gitgraph.js/blob/develop/src/gitgraph.js#L315), based on some moderately complicated math involving a bunch of values from the `template` object, plus a `scalingFactor` value derived using `window.devicePixelRatio`.

There doesn't seem to be a way to modify these values **before** the canvas is rendered, but using the provided `graph:render` event, you could do it **after**.

```
gitGraph.canvas.addEventListener("graph:render", function(event) {
  console.log(event.data.id, "has been rendered with a scaling factor of", gitGraph.scalingFactor);
  rescale();
}
function rescale() {
  var g = document.getElementById('gitGraph');
  var w = +g.style.width.slice(0,-2) * 0.5;  // < just change these two
  var h = +g.style.height.slice(0,-2) * 0.5; // multipliers to the same
  g.style.width = w + 'px';                  // value
  g.style.height = h + 'px';
};
```

Here's that function working with the official example code (notice that it does screw up the absolutely-positioned `detail` div):

http://codepen.io/phoward8020/pen/ZOpERB

Does that help?

(EDIT 2: Inline Stack Overflow example code added no value to answer since it's not editable. Replaced with CodePen so readers can verify functionality by changing multiplier values.)

Comment: That defines the styling and spacing info. Does it define the scale as well ?

Comment: Ah. Now I see what you're asking. gitgraph draws to an HTML `<canvas>` element. Have you tried [using the `scale()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations#Scaling) on the canvas?